# How to make a private track public using the Soundcloud API?

Tags: soundcloud

I can't seem to find a way to edit the `<sharing>` attribute of a track.
Is it even possible ?

If not, can you suggest a way to schedule the release of a track ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible using a `PUT` request on the track resource. Here's an example using curl:

```
curl -X PUT "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/<track_id>" -d"oauth_token=YOUR_TOKEN" -d"track[sharing]=public"
```

Obviously replace `<track_id>` with your actual track id and `YOUR_TOKEN` with your access token. The `track[sharing]` attribute can be either `private` or `public`.